# Unable to upload and retreive file from the database

Tags: html, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angular5

- I am trying to upload files for each course published by the Server section of the sofware Application and Firebase been used as database for this application.
- After choosing files from the device Storage and giving relevant deails to the text field and clicking on publish button, course gets published and chosen file converted into link and stored in database
- when trying to retrieve uploaded file from the training section for the intended course, it shows as sanitizing unsafe URL link and unable to see the file
- I have attached code for the above implementation, Kindly provide your suggestion to proceed further for the same

Server.component.html

```
<label for="user_data">Upload file</label>
      <input type="file" multiple formControlName="file" class="form-control" id="file" (change)=uploadFile($event) accept=".pdf,.docx" required>
```

Server.component.ts

```
uploadFile(event) {
        let Sport_files = event.target.files;
        if (Sport_files > 0) {
          console.log(this.sports_videoForm.value.file); // You will see the file link
          this.dataService.uploadFile(this.sports_videoForm.value.file);
        }
```

SportsData.service.ts (Service Component implementation)

```
uploadFile(file) {
        let formData: FormData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', file, file.name);

        this.http.post("http://localhost:/4200/", formData)
      }
```

retrieving file in training section for the intended course, sports_training.component.html

```
<a href="{{item.file}}" target="_blank" class="col-sm-4" style="padding-bottom: 10px">uploaded file</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make angular trust the url by using `bypassSecurityTrustUrl` method of [DomSanitizer](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer#bypasssecuritytrusturl)

You can create a common method in a service to be used across whole application as you might require this in multiple components in your application.

common.service.ts :

```
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

...

constructor(private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

sanitize(url: string){
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(url);
}
```

sports_training.component.html:

```
<a [href]="commonService.sanitize(item.file)" target="_blank" class="col-sm-4" style="padding-bottom: 10px">uploaded file</a>
```

You can create `sanitize` method in your sports_training component too but I recommend using a common service